# Preventing AJAX-called PHP-Script to execute a function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call of such form:

```
$("#assignDesigner .save").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("/cms/cms/php/update_di_user_designer_meta.php", $("#assignDesigner").serialize(), function(response) {
        alert("Update " + (response ? "worked" : "failed"));

        var data = {
            promoted_header: $(".product-promotion .rightcol > h3").html(),
            promoted_content: $(".product-promotion .rightcol > span").html(),
            promoted_owner: $("#designerSelection").val()
        };

        $.post("/cms/cms/php/create_di_promoted_products.php", data, function(response_inner) {
            $("section.product-promotion").replaceWith(response_inner);
        })
    })
});
```

My PHP-Script looks like this:

```
<?php
function insertCode($param)
{
    ...many echos...
}

if (isset($_POST))
{
    insertCode($_POST['param'])
}
?>
```

When called via AJAX the function should take the POST-Data in the `insertCode` function. When required or included the function is called with a different `$param`.

The Problem is, when I send my AJAX-Request the function is executed twice. First before the POST-Code is evaluated. So all the echoed text is sent back twice to the AJAX-Success-Function.

I have then tested whether the echoed text is sent back ich I comment the lower part with the test and yes even then the code of the function is echoed although I have never called the function.

How can I prevent the AJAX-call to help himself calling the function?

Comment: use `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: The problem sounds like a logic error in your JavaScript click handler. Add your click handler code that triggers the `$.post` and I bet the problem will be found.

Comment: I have called `e.preventDefault()` in my click-event-handler. About the event-handler itself I just added it. If it helps I would be glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue now and there were two problems.
First in my click-event-handler I used the `response` to replace the contents of a specific tag. But as long as there was an error in the PHP-Script the tag wasn't created again within the script which caused the output to stack on the page.

Secondly there was a bool variable in the PHP-Script which was not set when requested by the AJAX-Call.

Nontheless thank you for your answers. They helped very much resolving.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply, check within the PHP file, who or what is requesting the PHP file!

```
// If the request came from AJAX then do this
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] == "XMLHttpRequest") {
   // Perform Ajax related stuff
}
else {
   // Perform non-Ajax related stuff
}
```

Though, take in mind that headers can always be faked!